# how to fix overflow-y: scroll not working

Tags: html, css

I was trying to make the items in the `.menu-scroll` class which is a div of a `<ul>` list show a scroll bar when it passes its limites of the height, in my case it only keeps pushing down the `.menu-footer` div and making a huge problem in the page.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 300px 100px auto 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100vh;
}

.grid>#menu {
  display: grid;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2 end;
  grid-template-rows: auto 75px;
}

.grid>#posts-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-template-rows: 50px auto;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
}

#posts {
  background-color: white;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

.menu-footer {
  background-color: green;
}

.menu-scroll {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px auto;
}

.menu-scroll>.cover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.menu-scroll>.menu-list {
  position: sticky;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.list-item {
  background-color: tomato;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid" id="container">
  <div class="grid-item" id="menu">
    <div class="menu-scroll">
      <div class="cover">cover</div>
      <div class="menu-list">
        <ul style="list-style: none;">
          <li class="list-item">menu item</li>
          <li class="list-item">menu item</li>
          <li class="list-item">menu item</li>
          <li class="list-item">menu item</li>
          <li class="list-item">menu item</li>
          <li class="list-item">menu item</li>
          <li class="list-item">menu item</li>
          <li class="list-item">menu item</li>
          <li class="list-item">menu item</li>
          <li class="list-item">menu item</li>
          <li class="list-item">menu item</li>
          <li class="list-item">menu item</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-footer">sticky footer</div>

  </div>

  <div class="grid" id="posts-wrapper">
    <div id="posts">
      posts
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening because in your:

```
.menu-scroll {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px auto;
}
```

You set every element except for the first one in an `auto` sizing grid row. So no matter how many items you add to the `ul`, which is in the second element `<div class="menu-list">`, it will always grow.

You need to set it up to have an explicit height on the second element.

Like this:

```
.menu-scroll {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-rows: 100px 300px auto;
    }
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 300px 100px auto 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100vh;
}

.grid>#menu {
  display: grid;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2 end;
  grid-template-rows: auto 75px;
}

.grid>#posts-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-template-rows: 50px auto;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
}

#posts {
  background-color: white;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

.menu-footer {
  background-color: green;
}

.menu-scroll {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 300px auto;
}

.menu-scroll>.cover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.menu-scroll>.menu-list {
  position: sticky;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.list-item {
  background-color: tomato;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid" id="container">
  <div class="grid-item" id="menu">
    <div class="menu-scroll">
      <div class="cover">cover</div>
      <div class="menu-list">
        <ul style="list-style: none;">
          <li class="list-item">menu item</li>
          <li class="list-item">menu item</li>
          <li class="list-item">menu item</li>
          <li class="list-item">menu item</li>
          <li class="list-item">menu item</li>
          <li class="list-item">menu item</li>
          <li class="list-item">menu item</li>
          <li class="list-item">menu item</li>
          <li class="list-item">menu item</li>
          <li class="list-item">menu item</li>
          <li class="list-item">menu item</li>
          <li class="list-item">menu item</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-footer">sticky footer</div>

  </div>

  <div class="grid" id="posts-wrapper">
    <div id="posts">
      posts
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it fixed the scrollbar problem but still it doesnt fit the menu until the footer